# List item label problem

Tags: usability, design-patterns, lists, interface, labels

I'm facing a problem where I have a list item that has multiple values and one of them is a number that's ambiguous, therefore I want to label it. However a problem (in my opinion) that it creates is when having a list with multiple items this label becomes repetitive (see wireframe below). Any ideas how to communicate what that number means without repetitively showing value label? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What kind of value is it? The approach could differ depending on what kind of value you're trying to portray. For example it could be as simple as adding currency symbol for price.

Comment: Adding currency symbol for price is not the problem. The problem is communicating what time period the percentage value on the second row is referring to (in my example it's today). But showing this 'today' label in every list item makes this information repetitive and redundant. Hence the need for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Will there be other lists on screen, that are not "today"?

Comment: No, not on the same screen.

Answer (score 2):

If the value is extremely repetitive I would omit it completely from the list item itself. Place and show it in a parent container and group the items based on their "date" value.

[image]

Edit: Example where the grouping is done on page to page basis and the whole data set has the same value for the period.

[image]

Comment: Good example, however in my specific context the list will always have only one date value, which is a **period of time** not a specific date (either 1 day/1 month, etc). And if I use for example **1 day** as a label header that means that I'm omitting explaining the other data points in the list item (even though there might not be confusion to what data they refer to).

Comment: If the whole page has the same value for the period of time. Then I would use a similar approach as my example above. Again , omit it from the list item but add the period value as either title of the list or page.

Comment: Adding it in the title should give clear enough of an indication of what the list is about.